# jQuery datepicker input field set to "not clickable"

Tags: jquery-ui, input, datepicker

I have two input fields for datepicker - one set as active and second as `readonly`, but it looks like `readonly` is not working with datepicker. Code below.

HTML:

```
    <fieldset>
        <label for="dataStart">Start Date</label>
        <input type="text" style="width: 88px;" class="datepicker" id="dataStart" size="10" name="dataStart" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <label for="dataEnd">End Date</label>
       <input type="text" style="width: 88px;" class="end_date" id="dataEnd" size="10" name="dataEnd" value="" readonly />
    </fieldset>
<div>Days counted between dates: <span id="calculated"></span></div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#dataStart").datepicker({
        minDate: '+1d',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
        onSelect: function(date){
            var dates = date.split('/');
            var lastDate = new Date(dates[2], dates[0], 0);
            var y = lastDate.getFullYear(), m = lastDate.getMonth(), d = lastDate.getDate();
            m = ('0'+ (m+1)).slice(-2);

            $('#dataEnd').val(m+'/'+d+'/'+y);

            var start = $('#dataStart').datepicker('getDate');
            $('#dataEnd').datepicker({dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy'}).datepicker('setDate', m+'/'+d+'/'+y);
            var end = $('#dataEnd').datepicker('getDate');
            var days   = ((end - start)/1000/60/60/24)+1;

            $('#calculated').text(days);          
        }
    });
});
```

and [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/90kuhjcz/)

Comment: What is it that you're trying to do? Do you need the second input to have a datepicker or do you just need it to be filled with a value based on what's chosen in the first datepicker?

Comment: a read only input cannot be modified ! what you want is disabled attribute. However if you want to keep readonly, you've got to set readonly to false in your javascript before trying to change the value. That's mean in your code:  `$('#dataEnd').removeAttr('readonly');  ...set the value... then reset to readonly... `$('#dataEnd').attr('readonly', 'readonly');`

Comment: @j08691 second input field is to display a date based on first datepicker, but I need to pass that date to next step anyway.

Comment: So the second input doesn't even need a datepicker?

Comment: @j08691 nope, but need a data calculated based on a datepicker (see code)

Comment: @scraaappy where I should to use disable attribute?

Comment: in your html code, just replace readonly attribute by disabled in your input tag :  `<input type="text" style="width: 88px;" class="end_date" id="dataEnd" size="10" name="dataEnd" value="" disabled />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need a datepicker on the second input, then you can just not instantiate it like you're currently doing, and use this instead:

Remove:

```
$('#dataEnd').datepicker({dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy'}).datepicker('setDate', m+'/'+d+'/'+y);
```

and change:

```
var end = $('#dataEnd').datepicker('getDate');
```

to:

```
var end = new Date($('#dataEnd').val());
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/s7yhnmxL/)**

Comment: Bingo! I didn't know that `Date` can be set without datepicker. Thanks

Comment: Yup, Date is a native JS object.